# VirtualBox PXE with Windows Deployment Services not working

Tags: windows-server-2008, image, pxe-boot

I have a test environment with a VM Windows 2008 with WDS, DHCP, AD installed on it. I have a client (Acer Veriton N260G) that I want to install through PXE. The LAN connection works fine because I tested the connection with a laptop (ping, dhcp success).

But the damn Acer don't want to connect to the server. I don't even see the PXE option when I start up the boot menu (f12) en when I set the boot order to LAN first, nothing happens.. Only a error message that there was no boot manager found.

How can I start the PXE client on the Acer desktop?

### UPDATE

I'm using only vm now. I get the `FATAL: no bootable medium found! System halted.` error when trying to boot in LAN mode. The two vm are both configured to use the same internal network. I also added the options 66 and 67 to the DHCP without succes.

Is there a way to check if the PXE client is getting a IP or responce from the server? Because the boot sequence takes not even a second..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you enabled options 66 (Boot Server host name) and 67 (Bootfile name) in your DHCP server? [This](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX115094) link outlines the steps.

As far as booting from the network goes, looks like the hotkey is F10 not F12. See [this](http://putitbackinthebox.blogspot.com/2009/12/network-boot-on-acer-veriton-n260g.html).

Comment: I added the options as the guide descibed and added it to the ipv4 in the DHCP server. I have both vm's their network settings to the same intern network (I'm trying now with only vm). I boot from LAN but I keep getting the message `FATAL: no bootable medium found! System halted.`

Comment: Just watched the tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QhIx4ZL0IL0 on youtube. I have done exactly the same on my Windows 2008 server. Only difference is that he is using VMware and I'm using VirtualBox. :S

Comment: It works! I tried the Acer again and changed the BIOS LAN setting, and whola! Strange that my VirtualBox client's LAN doesn't work.. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 2):

Enable Network boot option in VM's system settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured BIOS first? Enter BIOS with Delete or something like F2.
I think you need enable PXE lan boot mode. Then change boot order.

Comment: Yeah, i already have done that. I also boot with the boot option mode, so that I don't have to set the boot order in the bios.